# Creating a chessboard mask to check the status of the squares on a chessboard

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I want to extract the squares from a chessboard and label each one of them according to their coordinates i.e. a1, a2, ... h8. My goal is to create a 'mask' to check the presence of a piece for each square. I am currently writing a program to do this in C# using Emgu CV.

The image used for testing can be found [here](http://www.sjgames.com/proteus/img/chessboard.jpg).

[image]

With no experience in computer vision, I have only been following simple code examples guided by basic ideas. My first lead was this [tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp) which tells me how to make a simple shape detector. It was not very accurate though as the test image is more complex than the example image.

*Inaccurate square detection (with a slightly different image)*

[image: Example]

There were two problems with the results: 1) not all of the squares were detected as squares; 2) 91 boxes (instead of 64) were created to visualise the detected squares.

To solve problem #1, I used a binary threshold with dilation and median smoothing to further 'simplify' the image and the results were much better but not complete (due to noise):

*After applying a binary threshold, dilating, median smoothing and eroding*

[image: binary threshold]

*Visualizing and counting the squares*

[image]

It appears that the same square(s) is detected multiple times (i.e. problem #2) for reasons unknown to me and I have no idea how to fix this. My initial idea was to give each square a label as soon as they were detected but it doesn't seem practical now.

### Questions

1. What method(s) can I use to remove the post-filter noise on squares b3 and g6?
2. What method(s) can I use to properly count and sort the squares in row-by-row order?
3. Assuming that I manage to label each square, how do I then 'save' the region of the square to be reused as a mask for newer frames? Is it computationally expensive to have 64 unique masks?
4. How can I maximize the detection rate of squares?

Comment: You've done a lot of good work!  Have you considered backing up a bit and simplifying the problem?  You've essentially made an algorithm that can count any n number of squares, of any color.  An easier problem is detecting a "chessboard," e.g. an 8x8 grid of alternating pattern.

Comment: @AdamFinley How should I go about detecting a grid of alternating pattern? I talked to some engineering students and one suggestion was to detect the intensity of the pixels from left to right whereby a steep in value signifies the edge of a different square. My problem right now is that I have the ideas, but I don't know how to implement them.

Comment: It's not clear in your question if you will be always applying the algorithm to the same chessboard (i.e. same viewpoint, scale, etc ) or if you're considering a generic situation. If this is the case, have you thought of using a fixed grid instead of detecting the squares? Imo this would greatly simplify the problem, and reduce your job to detecting one corner of the chessboard in order to position the grid, and then feed the image inside each square (which can be cropped) to a piece detection algorithm. I used this approach in a similar situation once, and it worked nicely.

Comment: @edu_ I was considering a generic situation e.g. a downward-facing camera mounted on an adjustable clamp. In my case, I could calibrate the program by adjusting the parameters of the processing functions until all squares are detected. Thanks for your suggestion on using a fixed grid, I will try to implement it. Did you have to deal with any distortion correction for the fixed grid method?

Comment: @Dennis, as you can see in my answer (which also can be used as a starting point for your implementation), the first few blue squares (counting from the top left corner) coincide almost perfectly with the chessboard squares, but this doesn't happen as we move towards the bottom right corner, indicating that either there is distortion, or the chessboard squares are not all the same size (or both). I haven't dealt with none of these situations, but strongly suggest you correct for distortion in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my comment in the original question, I implemented something that might serve as an example of fixed grid construction:

```
#define SQUARE_SIZE 131
#define OFFSET_X 75
#define OFFSET_Y 75
#define NUM_SQUARES_X 8
#define NUM_SQUARES_Y 8

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){

    // Directory settings
    const string pathToData = "../data/";

    vector<string> filenames = std::vector<string>();

    // Load filenames
    glob(pathToData, filenames, false);

    if(filenames.size() <= 0){
        cout << "no images were found..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }


    Mat chessboard = imread(pathToData+"chessboard.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    for (int i=0;i<NUM_SQUARES_X;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<NUM_SQUARES_Y;j++){

            int startX = OFFSET_X + SQUARE_SIZE*i;
            int startY = OFFSET_Y + SQUARE_SIZE*j;
            int endX = startX + SQUARE_SIZE;
            int endY = startY + SQUARE_SIZE;

            rectangle(chessboard, Point(startX,startY), Point(endX,endY), Scalar(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0);
        }
    }

    namedWindow("chessboard", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("chessboard", chessboard);  

    cv::waitKey(0); 

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Of course you'll have to fine tune the parameters (offset and square dimensions), since I didn't spend much time on it.